# GLUT not updating after CPU time changes

Tags: linux, glut

We had an interesting anomaly with GLUT/Intel/Linux this week.

After setting the CPU time back 2 minutes, our GLUT window would not update for 2 minutes.

Does GLUT use the CPU time for updating the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The freeglut git repo shows [added support for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in 2012](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/commit/9c6c6850d032c4ba46).

If you have a version of GLUT that uses `gettimeofday` instead of `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)`, code that is driven by [fghCheckTimers](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/src/fg_main.c#L221) would probably behave like you describe when setting the time back.